# Javascript executing button click on page event

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and I'm trying to see if what I want to do is possible.  I want to take a current webpage that I have open in my browser, and execute new javascript.  There is a timer on this page, and when it increases to a particular time, I want it to execute a button click.

This would be the time that is changing and that I want to add into a if statement:

07:34:04

Will this changing time raise an event that would cause a javascript to run?  I want something along the lines of:

if time = 7:35:00 then click button.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: post some codes what you've tried

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Rerun their code or issue the callback. This question, however, is not a good fit for the Q&A format of stack overflow.

Comment: how do you define the time when click action should happen? is it on next full minute, after 56 seconds or what?

Answer (score 0):

I'll like to make a contribution..
I don't know much about the javascript time format, but I'll post back if I can look it up.
Any way you can use a function such as this:

```
var waiter;
function waitForTimer(extime, fn)
{
  //Here, fn is the function to be executed..
  //While extime is the time at which the function is to be executed..

  waiter = setInterval(function(fn,extime){
     //this function will check every one second..
     if( extime == time )
     {
        fn();
        clearInterval(waiter);
     }
     else
        log("waiting for " + time);
  }, 1000);
}
```

I hope this helps.